# How to exit a program: sys.stderr.write() or print

Tags: python, error-handling

I am writing a small app and I need to quit the program multiple number of times.

Should I use:

`sys.stderr.write('Ok quitting')`
`sys.exit(1)`

Or should I just do a:

`print 'Error!'`
`sys.exit(1)`

Which is better and why? Note that I need to do this a lot. The program should completely quit.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
sys.exit('Error!')
```

Note from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit):

> If another type of object is passed,
>   None is equivalent to passing zero,
>   and any other object is printed to
>   sys.stderr and results in an exit code
>   of 1. In particular, sys.exit("some
>   error message") is a quick way to exit
>   a program when an error occurs.

Answer (score 17):

They're two different ways of showing messages.

`print` generally goes to `sys.stdout` and you know where `sys.stderr` is going. It's worth knowing the difference between [stdin, stdout, and stderr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).

`stdout` should be used for normal program output, whereas `stderr` should be reserved only for error messages (abnormal program execution). There are utilities for splitting these streams, which allows users of your code to differentiate between normal output and errors.

`print` can print on any file-like object, including `sys.stderr`:

```
print >> sys.stderr, 'My error message'
```

The advantages of using `sys.stderr` for errors instead of sys.stdout are:

1. If the user redirected `stdout` to a file, they still see errors on the screen.
2. It's unbuffered, so if `sys.stderr` is redirected to a log file there is less chance that the program will crash before the error was logged.

It's worth noting that there's a third way you can provide a closing message:

```
sys.exit('My error message')
```

This will send a message to `stderr` and exit.

Answer (score 10):

If it's an error message, it should normally go to `stderr` - but whether this is necessary depends on your use case. If you expect users to redirect `stdin`, `stderr` and `stdout`, for example when running your program from a different tool, then you should make sure that status information and error messages are separated cleanly.

If it's just you using the program, you probably don't need to bother. In that case, you might as well just raise an exception, and the program will terminate on its own.

By the way, you can do

```
print >>sys.stderr, "fatal error"     # Python 2.x
print("fatal error", file=sys.stderr) # Python 3.x
```

Comment: Does `sys.exit ("some error message")` work for both Python 2 and 3?

Comment: @jww: Yes, it does.